# WP7 finger friendly controls size

Tags: windows-phone-7

Which would be the best size for different WP7 controls(like listview items, buttons etc) in order to be "finger friendly"? Is any resource that handle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [UI Design and Interaction Guide for Windows Phone 7 v2.0](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218):

> Touch targets should not be smaller than 9 mm or 34 pixels square and 
>   provide at least 2 mm or 8 pixels between touchable controls. In excep-
>   tional cases, controls can be smaller but never more than 7 mm or 26 
>   pixels square. The on-screen keyboard and hyperlinks in Windows Phone® 
>   Internet Explorer® are an exception because they have differently sized hit 
>   targets.